# Road distances between lakes QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-plugins, distance, linestring

I've got a dataset of about ~120 lakes (multipolygon) and and another one of roads (multistring line), and I need to determine the road distance from each lake to every other lake in the dataset, using QGIS 3.12.2.

I've been able to do this with QNEAT3, but that only works on points.  Since each lake has multiple ingress and egress locations, point files will not give me the correct distances.

Here's a screenshot example.  As you can see, there are multiple roads to each lake and each lake is highly branched, but one path from from one point on the lake will be the shortest.

I've tried NNJOIN, but it never moves off of zero percent, just kind of hangs.  I've also found that the MMQGIS plugin may work, but after reading about it, I don't think it will.

Anyone have any ideas?

[image]

---

D'Oh!
I created the layer then ran the code on a couple of test layers, and still received an error.[image]

---

Ok, so pulling on my vast (meaning infintesimal) knowledge of Python I did some code changes, and I'm not getting the same error as I did before.  Using good 'ol Print, I'm able to see why nothing is happening.  In the picture below, the red line is State Hwy 15, while the lake in the picture is Sooner lake.  Please note that the highway intersects the lake several times and is very close to it at a number of points.
However the code returns the following distance values from State Hwy 15 to Sooner Lake (reformated here of course).

Sooner Lake - State Hwy 15: 1485956.665928024

Sooner Lake - State Hwy 15: 1485956.733344301

These distance values are too big to be meters, km, inches or feet, so I don't understand what the units are for the values.  Since they are all > 20, which is the max_distance set in the code, they are rejected.

I have no idea what is happening here.  Yes, much of the code is commented out, as I just needed to get some values to start with.

Help!

Also, not knowing how to post pics, etc in replies, I've made a new "answer", admins, please let me know if this is incorrect and if it is how to fix it.

[image]

```
from collections import defaultdict
import networkx as nx
from itertools import product

roadlyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('testroads')[0] #Change to match your road layer name
lakelyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('test')[0] #Same
exroadlyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('roads_explode_lines')[0] #The road layer after "Explode lines" processing tool
max_distance = 20 #From lake to road

roadlyr.selectAll()
lakelyr.selectAll()
exroadlyr.selectAll()

print(roadlyr)
print(lakelyr)
print(exroadlyr)
print(max_distance)

print('lakelyr')
selection = lakelyr.selectedFeatures()
#print(selection)
print(len(selection))

print('roadlyr')
selection2 = roadlyr.selectedFeatures()
#print(selection2)
print(len(selection2))

print('exroadlyr')

selection3 = exroadlyr.selectedFeatures()
#print(selection3)
print(len(selection3))



#FIND NEARBY ROADS AND EACH ROAD SINGLE CLOSEST VERTEX
d = defaultdict(list)
for lake in lakelyr.getFeatures():
#    print(lake.geometry())
    for road in roadlyr.getFeatures():
        if lake['Name'] == 'Sooner Lake':
            if road['FULLNAME'] == 'State Hwy 15':
                print(lake['Name'])
                print(road['FULLNAME'])
                print(lake.geometry().distance(road.geometry()))
#        print(lake.geometry().distance(road.geometry()))
#        print(road)
        if lake.geometry().distance(road.geometry())<=max_distance or lake.geometry().intersects(road.geometry()):
            print('true')
            d[lake].append(road)
#
#start_and_ends = [] #This is the result holding all start and end vertices
#for lake, roads in d.items():
#    #print(lake,road)
#    temp_vertlist = []
#    for road in roads:
#        vertlist = [v for v in road.geometry().vertices()]
#        closest_vertice = min(vertlist, key=lambda x: lake.geometry().distance(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(x))))
#        #temp_vertlist.append(closest_vertice)
#        temp_vertlist.append((round(closest_vertice.x()),round(closest_vertice.y())))
#    start_and_ends.append(temp_vertlist)
#
##CREATE A NETWORKX GRAPH
#G = nx.Graph()
#for feat in exroadlyr.getFeatures():
#    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104610/fastest-way-to-get-the-first-and-last-element-of-a-python-iterator
#    g = feat.geometry()
#    first = last = next(g.vertices())
#    for last in g.vertices():
#        pass
#    first = (round(first.x()), round(first.y()))
#    last = (round(last.x()), round(last.y()))
#    roadlength = round(g.length(),0)
#    G.add_edge(first, last, weight=roadlength, lineid=feat.id(), linegeom=feat.geometry())
#
#paths = []
#for start, end in product(start_and_ends[0], start_and_ends[1]):
#    try:
#        p = (nx.dijkstra_path(G, start, end, weight='weight'))
#        paths.append(p)
#    except:
#        pass
#
##Create a line layer for all paths
#vl = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs={}&index=yes".format(roadlyr.crs().authid()), "all_paths", "memory")
#provider = vl.dataProvider()
#for p in paths:
#    gLine = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPoint(x,y) for x,y in p])
#    f = QgsFeature()
#    f.setGeometry(gLine)
#    provider.addFeature(f)
#QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
#
##Select shortest path
#all_paths = [f for f in vl.getFeatures()]
#shortest_path = min(all_paths, key=lambda x: x.geometry().length())
#vl.select(shortest_path.id())
#
#print('Done')
```

Comment: How close must the end of a road line segment be to a lake polygon in order to be of interest?

Comment: Can *any* road segment be considered. For calculating distance?

Comment: Ideally the roads should touch the lake.  If they don't the one nearest to touching the lake is needed.  Any road segment or series of road segments can be considered.

Comment: No, I do not.  Looked at them, but haven't installed them.  Using Imac with 10.14.16

Comment: Thanks, I missed that 's'.  renamed the "road_explode_lines" to "roads_explode_lines".  I reran the code and I'm still getting the exact same error.  Just not up on Python.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: @gwfami Please **[edit]** your question with updates and new information rather than adding numerous comments and answers.  The answer spaces are reserved for answers to the question, not for you to add additional information